# Google Sheets: Insert Link Increases Font Size

Tags: google-sheets

In a financials spreadsheet I have to insert a lot of Links, and Sheets always increases the font size, eg from the default 10 to 12.

Also, when I paste a formula into a cell, both the font size and colour get changed.

Is there a setting to prevent this annoying behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

after your paste you can press <kbd>**`CTRL + A`**</kbd> and <kbd>**`CTRL + \`**</kbd>

[image]

this will result in defaulting the formatting

---

or you can try <kbd>**`CTRL + SHIFT + V`**</kbd>

[image]

---

and the 3rd option would be to use mediate paste... copy and paste it somewhere where formatting is not supported like address bar, notepad (txt file), translate.google.com box... and then copypaste it into your sheet

---

there is also another option if your paste is only in one cell (not across cells). you either double click on the cell and then paste it or paste it right into formula bar/box instead of the cell

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions,  CTL + \  helps.  Pity that there is no option in Sheets to prevent this in the first place though.